# Gitlab CI job to run after each deployment for reporting status

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to send a report about the status of deployment to a rest API.
It should be independent from deploy job (because of $IMAGE2 dependency) since I want to use report job in other projects.
So I created two jobs in Gitlab CI like this:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: $IMAGE1
  script:
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} && echo 'Failed' > deployment-status
    # some codes to deploy and exit 1 if not successful
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} && echo 'Passed' > deployment-status  #This line run only when deployment is successful
  when: manual
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - deployment-status

report-deployment:
  stage: post-deploy
  image: $IMAGE2
  script:
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} && cat deployment-status
    # some codes to report the status of deployment to an API
  when: always
  needs: ["deploy"]
```

In the above solution, depend on deployment, I fill `deployment-status` with Passed/Failed and use `deployment-status` artifact file in the next job to get information about deployment status and report it.

The solution above has some problems:
  - Pipeline status would be `running` unless I trigger the manual job. (because of `report-deployment` job that needs `deploy`)
  - If I try to trigger the `deploy` job twice, only one report being sent to API.
[Image of problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhuM0.png)

Comment: Hi. Why not just put API call into the `deploy` stage?

Comment: I want `report-deployment` job be a separate job (template like) that can be used in other projects. and it's not clean to merge $IMAGE1 and $IMAGE2 dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I just realised that his a old post, but this solution might still be helpful to others.

From my understanding of pipelines it's not possible to have a job automatically trigger again once it's completed.

We had a similar problem which we solved by using the [gitlab job API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html):

What you can do is to create a script which calls the [Play a Job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#play-a-job) endpoint.
This script should be called in your deployment job in the [after_script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#after_script), so it's only triggered once your deployment is done.

You further have to set the *report-deployment* job to manual execution.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: $IMAGE1
  script:
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} && echo 'Failed' > deployment-status
    # some codes to deploy and exit 1 if not successful
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} && echo 'Passed' > deployment-status
  after_script:
    - <path_to_report_deployment_script>
  when: manual
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - deployment-status

report-deployment:
  stage: post-deploy
  image: $IMAGE2
  script:
    - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} && cat deployment-status
  when: manual # changed to manual
  needs: ["deploy"]
```

The script that calls the *report_deployment* job requires only the project id and pipeline id, which you can get from the *CI_PROJECT_ID* and *CI_PIPELINE_ID* environment variables. This allows you to [List Pipeline Jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs) via the API.

Iterate over the job list till you find the *report-deployment* job and save the job id. With the project id and job id you can now trigger the *Play a Job* API call.

If you want to get rid of the artifact creation, you can play around a bit. While the API doesn't allow you to pass a variable to the job there is probably a way around it. Off the top of my head I could imagine *report_successful_deployment* and *report_failed_deployment* jobs and you let the script decide which one should be triggered.